# How to set reponseType as blob for $http in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs

i need to set response Type as 'blob' in angular.
how to set response Type for $http in angularjs?
sample code for set responseType using  XMLHttpRequest is provided below. i need to replace XMLHttpRequest with $http.

```
var oMyForm = new FormData();
oMyForm.append("js", content);
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest({mozSystem: true});
oReq.open("POST", url, true);
oReq.responseType = "blob";
oReq.onload = function(xhr) {

};
oReq.onerror = function(xhr) {

};
oReq.send(oMyForm);
```

Comment: Why is your code not working? What error do you catch?

Comment: here i used XMLHttpRequest,need to replace with $http in angularjs

Answer (score 15):

angular provides config object for that , check [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

```
  $http({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/example/teste",
        method: "POST",
        responseType: "blob"

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in IE, Chrome and FF.

```
function download(url) {
    if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open("GET", url, true);
        ajax.responseType = 'blob';
        ajax.onload = function(e) {
            navigator.msSaveBlob(data, url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
        };
    } else {
        $('#download-frame').remove();
        $('<iframe/>', {
            src: url,
            id: 'download-frame'
        }).hide().appendTo('body');
    }
}
```